# How to transfer/push table from one database to another using dblink

Tags: postgresql, dblink

Say we have 2 databases in postgresql: `Database A`(with dblink extension installed) and `Database B` (without dblink extension)

Copying table from `B` to `A` looks fairly straightforward:

```
select * into table_from_B from dblink('dbname=B', 'select id, name from some_table') as t(id bigint, name varchar(255));
```

What is the best way to copy/push a particular table from `A` to `B` using SQL?

Is it possible to do it using `dblink` without installing it on `B` ?

Comment: Why not use postgres_fdw instead of dblink?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! As I can see `create foreign table` and `import foreign schema` provide `pull` functionality, however I'm curious to know if there is a way to `push` table to foreign server.

Comment: You can insert into a declared foreign table, not just select from it. So it provides both push and pull